# radio button value="dahiliLink" values empty posting

Tags: jquery, html, forms, bootstrap-modal, posts

i have one text box and one drop down menu. these show/hide with two radio buttons.
this value="hariciLink" values is posting successfuly, but this value="dahiliLink" values is posting empty. how can i fix this issue?
thanks for the answers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="hariciLink"){
            $(".box").not(".hariciLink").hide();
            $(".hariciLink").fadeIn(300);
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="dahiliLink"){
            $(".box").not(".dahiliLink").hide();
            $(".dahiliLink").fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
});
</script>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ikon" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Bağlantı</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="link" value="hariciLink"> Harici Link</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="link" value="dahiliLink"> Dahili Link</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box form-group dahiliLink">
    <label for="link" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Seçiniz</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10 selectContainer">
        <select name="link" value="" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="white">White</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box form-group hariciLink">
    <label for="link" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Link</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Örnek: http://www.websayfam.com" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>

$data = array();
if (isset($_GET['files'])) {
    $error = false;
    $files = array();
    $uniqid = uniqid();
    $uploaddir = '../../images/'.$uniqid;
    foreach($_FILES as $file) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.basename($file['name']))) {
            $files[] = $uploaddir.$file['name'];
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    $data = ($error) ? array('error' = > 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' = > $files);
} else {
    $arr - > image = $file['name'];
    $_SESSION['image'] = "img-".$file['name'];
    $arr - > ok = "ok";
    $data = array('success' = > 'Form was submitted', 'formData' = > $file['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is so because when you have multiple radio buttons with the same name, only the selected radio button's value is posted as the value for that name.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. how can i fix it? because i have a php form like this.

 $isim  = $_POST['isim'];
    $ikon  = $_POST['ikon'];
    $ustmenude = isset($_POST['ustmenudeGizle']) ? $_POST['ustmenudeGizle'] : 0;
    $link   = $_POST['link'] == NULL ? '#' : $_POST['link'];

Comment: What exactly do you want to post? You want to send both those values to the server? if that's the case, you can use `input` tags. You can use hidden inputs if you do not want to display those e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="value1" value="hariciLink" />    <input type="hidden" name="value2" value="dahiliLink" />`

Comment: i don't want sent both values. just i will select with radio button, then i fill and then i will send. just it is. but if i select from dropdown, value posting empty. how can i fix it?